# Angular2 using http.get with a distinct

Tags: http, angular, rxjs

I am trying to learn more about the Http.Get. I am using a json file to mock the HTTP call. After the call I want to limit the rows to unique states. I know there is an Rxjs command called distinct ([help on Rxjs distinct](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html)). However I do not understand the syntax for the distinct.   When I run this code as is I get an array of states.  However when I add the distinct it still has duplicated states like Texas.

```
    public getStates(): Observable<IState[]> {
    return this._http.get(this.stateUrl)
      .map((res: Response) => <IState[]>res.json())
      // distinct by state name
       .distinct((x) => return x.state)
     ;
  }
```

Here is the interface for IState

```
export interface IState {
  id: number;
  state: string;
  city: string;
  name: string;
}
```

Trying to only get rows with a unique state.

I have repo for the code on [this Github project](https://github.com/ATXGearHead12/distinct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing a bit the meaning of the distinct in this situation!
This `distinct` is meant to filter the response from your Observable, not its content! Here you're trying to "distinct" (filter) your json object, but the distinct will filter the responses (multiple) "resolved" by the Observable. So, if the observable "resolves" the same response multiple times, you'll receive only once, because of your `.distinct`.
This means, if the 1st time the Observable returns you back one json (e.g [{0: a, 1:b, 2:c}]) and the second time he returns the same json reponse, then your "subscribers" will not receive it twice, because the `.distinct` will "filter" it and as a result it will not be fired!

more details here: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/distinct.md

So, what you're looking for, is how to "filter" duplicated results within your json.
The answer is simple: use a loop to check its properties/values or some library like underscore which might have this method already implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the information.   You are right I was totally out in left field.  From what your saying I should edit the data in the subscribe function instead of the http.get observable creator?

Comment: you're right, you have to parse the list/object in the subscribe in order to remove the duplicated values

Answer (score 0):

The `IState` is an object. You have to define what exactly makes them *distinct* from each other.You can look at the [documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/distinct.md), there is a way to define what makes an object *distinct*

For example:

```
/* Without key selector */
var source = Rx.Observable.of(42, 24, 42, 24)
  .distinct();

var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('Next: %s', x);
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: %s', err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });

// => Next: 42
// => Next: 24
// => Completed

/* With key selector */
var source = Rx.Observable.of({value: 42}, {value: 24}, {value: 42}, {value: 24})
    .distinct(function (x) { return x.value; });

var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('Next: %s', x);
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: %s', err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });

// => Next: { value: 42 }
// => Next: { value: 24 }
// => Completed
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you're calling `.distinct((x) => return x.state)` the `x` variable is the entire array from https://github.com/ATXGearHead12/distinct/blob/master/src/api/state.json. Then property `x.state` doesn't exists.

So you need to call distinct on each item in the array not on the array itself.

For example like the following:

```
this._http.get(this.stateUrl)
    .map((res: Response) => <IState[]>res.json())
    .concatMap(arr => 
        Observable.from(arr).distinct((x) => return x.state)
    )
    .toArray(); // collect all items into an array
```

Comment: Hey martin,  I edited your code for the syntax errors I am getting.    Not sure from tv comment if i should be modify the data in http.get or whether I should be doing it in the subscribe method.